# Is there an action of a group on the set of its finite quotients?

Tags: group-theory

Is there an action (which turns out to be useful) of a group $G$ on the set (or isomorphism classes) of  its finite quotients?

Comment: Does it have to be the group $G$ itself? $\text{Out}(G)$ acts on the set of finite-index normal subgroups in an obvious way.